# Get file paths for multiple uploaded files with angular-file-upload within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using Angular 1 and the `angular-file-upload` plugin.

I want to create an array populated in the following way:

```
result = [{
  name: "whatever string",
  uploadedFilePath: "/whatever/path/image.png"
}, {
  name: "other string",
  uploadedFilePath: "/whatever/path/otherImage.png"
}]
```

In the view I have an `ng-repeat` with a name input and a file-input field and a button that creates another card with the same fields in the `ng-repeat`.

I can add the names to the array in the corresponding objects without much issue.

If there is a single upload input and not in the `ng-repeat` (either file input or multiple) I can easily get the path by taking it through the event:

```
vm.uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
  vm.uploadedFilePaths.push(response.filePath);
};
```

and then getting the paths from `vm.uploadedFilePaths`.

I don't know any good practices for showing the file input in the view so I'm using:

```
<input type="file" ng-file-model="files" multiple />
<p ng-repeat="file in files">
  {{file.name}}
</p>
```

I don't know how to get the paths corresponding to each of the uploaded files and adding them to the corresponding object in the array.

I'm somewhat confident I should be using the event `vm.uploader.uploadAll();` at the end to put them in the corresponding place ? But how do I find out the corresponding place for each, I'm not sure how I can utilize `$index` here.

I'm very new to using `angular-file-upload` so I'd appreciate it very much if you could explain it like it's for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a object as

```
vm.fileDetails = {
                       name:"",
                       path:""
                      }
```

and then on the completion of upload

```
vm.uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
  vm.fileDetails.name = response.fileName;
  vm.fileDetails.path = response.filePath;
  vm.uploadedFilePaths.push(vm.fileDetails);
};
```

Now you can use this array in your view to get details.